# Запуск процедуру в контексте другого сервера

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Допустим, есть 1 сервер статистики и 10 серверов с которых собирается статистика.
Можно ли расположить на Сервере статистики процедуру, а потом при опросе 10 серверов, через код сослаться на нее и выполнить в контексте другого сервера?(Сервера на линкованные).

Можно конечно на всех серверах развернуть процедуру, но будет не очень удобно их обновлять.

Comment: Это реализуемо с помощью систем управления развёртыванием и конфигурацией: Ansible, Chef, Puppet, Saltstack и т.п. Но это решение совсем не средствами .NET. Если это вас устроит — сообщайте, тогда я дам более подробный ответ.

Comment: Кстати, метку [программирование] не нужно использовать, она слишком обобщённая.

Comment: А нельзя считать код процедуры из Сервера статистики и применить его на других серверах? Тогда бы на других серверах, всегда была бы актуальная процедура и не нужно было ручками переносить изменения на 10 серверов.

Comment: я не вполне понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под кодом процедуры. Можете привести пример и объяснить, что процедура должна делать?